# Smallest sum of elements in a set

Tags: number-theory

Let $S$ equal to a set that contains $n$ numbers. Find the elements of $S$ so that the sum of the elements in $S$ is the smallest where the product of any 2 numbers in $S$ is a multiple of $k$.

For example, if $n  = 4$ and $k = 28$ then $S = \{2, 14, 28, 42\}$.

What I've tried is for $n=2$ then $S$ is just the the factors of $k$ that has the smallest sum.

Are there any general algorithms to find the elements of $S$?

Comment: Please edit your question as to show us what youy've been trying sofar and where you got stuck. Noone will help you unless you show some work.